# How to display two table rows on single click in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have one class which contains two more classes like hierarchy. When I'm displaying in Telerik RadGrid it should display like, when we click on first class row then it should display two rows of related classes as in below figure. Could help me to do this..?

[image]

Comment: How is this different from the Master/Detail hierarchy http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchyserverside or http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailsserverside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered your previous post, I just took my other answer and modified it to do what you are looking for. The following is the addition of a class that stores hobby info. I then added the needed structure and relations (the different colored squares denote the different classes):

[image]

**Note: The changes here are minimal and the changes are commented as //New something// so they should be easy to see.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void RadGrid1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DefineGridStructure();
}

private void DefineGridStructure()
{
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "EmpId" };

    RadGrid1.Width = Unit.Percentage(98);
    RadGrid1.PageSize = 5;
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
    RadGrid1.AllowSorting = true;
    RadGrid1.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
    RadGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    RadGrid1.ShowStatusBar = true;

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageSize = 5;

    //Add columns
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn;
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "EmpId";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "EmpId";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Name";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Name";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Age";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Age";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    //Detail table - Orders (II in hierarchy level)
    GridTableView tableViewOrders = new GridTableView(RadGrid1);
    tableViewOrders.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    tableViewOrders.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "EmpId" };

    GridRelationFields relationFields = new GridRelationFields();
    relationFields.MasterKeyField = "EmpId";
    relationFields.DetailKeyField = "EmpId";
    tableViewOrders.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields);

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders);

    //Add columns
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Street";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Street";
    tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "City";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "City";
    tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Zip";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Zip";
    tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);


    //New Detail Table #2 - adds in a another class that stores data


    GridTableView tableViewOrders2 = new GridTableView(RadGrid1);
    tableViewOrders2.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    tableViewOrders2.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "EmpId" };

    GridRelationFields relationFields2 = new GridRelationFields();
    relationFields2.MasterKeyField = "EmpId";
    relationFields2.DetailKeyField = "EmpId";
    tableViewOrders2.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields2);

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders2);

    //Add columns
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "HobbyName";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "HobbyName";
    tableViewOrders2.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    List<Employee> empList = GetEmployeeDetails();

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet("DataSet");

    System.Data.DataTable dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt1.TableName = "Employee";
    dt1.Columns.Add("EmpId");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Age");
    dataset.Tables.Add(dt1);

    System.Data.DataTable dt2 = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt2.TableName = "Address";
    dt2.Columns.Add("EmpId");
    dt2.Columns.Add("Street");
    dt2.Columns.Add("City");
    dt2.Columns.Add("Zip");
    dataset.Tables.Add(dt2);


    //New datatable that stores the new classes' data
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    dt3.TableName = "Hobby";
    dt3.Columns.Add("EmpId");
    dt3.Columns.Add("HobbyName");
    dataset.Tables.Add(dt3);


    foreach (Employee emp in empList)
    {
        dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { emp.EmpId, emp.Name, emp.Age });

        foreach (Address add in emp.Address)
        {
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { emp.EmpId, add.Street, add.City, add.Zip });
        }
        //New data add loop
        foreach (Hobby hob in emp.Hobby)
        {
            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { emp.EmpId, hob.HobbyName });
        }


    }

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataSource = dataset.Tables["Employee"];
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables[0].DataSource = dataset.Tables["Address"];
    //Add the new table to the grid
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables[1].DataSource = dataset.Tables["Hobby"];
}

private List<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails()
{
    List<Employee> myEmployees = new List<Employee>();

    Employee Steve = new Employee()
    {
        Address = new List<Address>() { new Address { City = "op", Street = "thatstreet", Zip = 23312 } },
        Hobby = new List<Hobby>() { new Hobby() { HobbyName = "Skating" } },
        Age = 23,
        EmpId = "Emp1",
        Name = "SteveIsTheName"
    };


    Employee Carol = new Employee()
    {
        Address = new List<Address>() {
                    new Address { City = "op2", Street = "thatstreet2", Zip = 23313 },
                    new Address { City = "op3", Street = "thatstreet3", Zip = 23314 }},
        Hobby = new List<Hobby>() { new Hobby() { HobbyName = "Fishing" } },
        Age = 24,
        EmpId = "Emp2",
        Name = "CarolIsTheName"
    };

    myEmployees.Add(Steve);
    myEmployees.Add(Carol);

    return myEmployees;
}
}

class Employee
{
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }

    public List<Hobby> Hobby { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EmpId { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public int Zip { get; set; }
}

class Hobby
{
    public string HobbyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Then whats the structure of RadGrid in .aspx page..? Should we create MasterTableView and DetailTables in .aspx page..? If I created only <RadGrid></RadGrid> then its giving the error as System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection, near RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables[0].DataSource = dataset.Tables["Address"];

Comment: Hey its working.. But 'EmpId' is displaying in every row of every classes. How to avoid this..?

Comment: Assuming you are defining the structure of the grid as I did, you would make sure you do not add EmpID as a column under the DefineGridStructure() method. Where you see "street,city, and zip" columns being added, you must make sure you only add the columns you wish to see. If you post your code, minus any private data, I'd help point out any lines of code you do not need.